# How do mobiles applications store their history. What is the mechanism

Tags: android, mobile, browser

Every browser stores history of web pages we visit, I am curious if mobile apps work similarly, what is the mechanism.
What happens when we press the back button, how does the app know which page to open up?

Comment: Apps will go to pause lifecycle

Comment: There is data structure called "stack", its very simple yet powerful. Stack: first in, last out, you can think of it as can of pringles you can only take from top. When you navigate through your app, every activity is put into backstack, when you press back the top most activity is removed from stack, thus the activity below it is resumed. If there is only one activty in stack app gets closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are calling "pages" is actually termed as "activities" in android. To answer your question, every android app maintains it's own **Backstack** to keep track of the visited activities.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack?authuser=2),

> The activities are arranged in a stack—the back stack)—in the order in which each activity is opened. For example, an email app might have one activity to show a list of new messages. When the user selects a message, a new activity opens to view that message. This new activity is added to the back stack. If the user presses the Back button, that new activity is finished and popped off the stack. The following video provides a good overview of how the back stack works.